# Should I transmit local variable to partial template or just use instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a partial template, and I call it like this:

```
<%= render 'postBlock' %>
```

In this template:

```
<%= content_tag(:h1, @post.title) %>
<%= markdown(@post.content) %>
```

I am confused that should I try the method like below:

```
<%= render 'postBlock', post: @post %>
```

```
<%= content_tag(:h1, post.title) %>
<%= markdown(post.content) %>
```

Can someone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Either works but my preference would be `post: @post` as it would let you reuse the partial in other circumstances where you might substitute something other than `@post`... for example if you were doing several posts...

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render 'postBlock', post: post %>
<% end %>
```

And that would require no change to the partial if you need to do this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are good, use locals where you load a page and from there you want to pass a value to the partial template, you can pass easily.
using locals like below

<%= render partial: 'postBlock', locals: {message: message} %>

and in that partials, you can use a local variable message like this <%= message %>